# QPainter drawText() in QGLWidget draw long Chinese text with English upside down

Tags: qt, opengl, drawing, qglwidget

I use codes below to draw text in QGLWidget, but when the text is long and mixed Chinese(or Japanese) with English, then the text becomes upside down. Anyone knows why?

PS1: When I change QGLWidget to QWidget, everything is OK.

PS2: My Qt version is 4.8.0, OS is Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

PS3: When I firstly draw the text into an image, then draw that image, everything is ok.

Normal when using QWidget:
[image: normal text]

Upside-down when using QGLWidget:
[image: upside down text]

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QGLWidget>

class MainWindow : public QGLWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QGLWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QGLWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{
    setGeometry(0, 0, 1000, 200);
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(this);

    QString text = QString::fromLocal8Bit(
                "THIS IS一段A很长的LONG示例文本TEXT。在非常长的时候会出现上下  颠倒的问题。你那里是否出现了？" \
                "一段很长的示例文本。在非常长的时候会出现上下颠倒的问题。你那里是否出现了？" \
                "一段很长的示例文本。在非常长的时候会出现上下颠倒的问题。你那里是否出现了？"
                );

    painter.setFont(QFont("default", 46, -1, false));
    painter.drawText(QRect(0, 0, 3000, 200), Qt::TextSingleLine, text);
    painter.end();
}
```

**

### Edit:

**

I change font family name "default" to "YaHei Consolas Hybrid", it becomes normal when only drawText once. But When I use codes below to change text at intervals, the Chinese Characters become upside down again...

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QGLWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{
    setGeometry(0, 0, 2000, 100);

    paintTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(paintTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(repaint()));
    paintTimer->start(16);

    text1 ="【中文1024测试】ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ中文ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"\
            "中文ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ中文ABCDEFGHIJKLMN";

    text2 = "中文English中文English中文English中文English中文Englis中文";

    text = text2;

    offset = 0;
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(this);

    painter.setFont(QFont("YaHei Consolas Hybrid", 40, -1, false));
    painter.drawText(QRect(0, 0, 3000, 100), Qt::TextSingleLine, text);
    painter.end();

    offset= (offset + 8) %400;

    if (offset > 200) {
        text = text1;
    } else {
        text = text2;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QFont>

class MainWindow : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QGLWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);
private:
    QTimer* paintTimer;
    QString text1;
    QString text2;
    QString text;
    int offset;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Qt's painter treats the top left of the screen as (0,0), and Open GL uses the bottom left, which may have something to do with this: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2012/12/17/on-the-coordinate-system-of-qgraphicsscene-in-qt/

Comment: I run above code on windows, but no issue.

Comment: @Merlin069 But when I delete some characters from the string which make it quite short, it's OK. Also you can see the English in the image is OK.

Comment: @olive could it possible be a bug on Ubuntu...

Comment: @olive can you change the font size to a bigger or smaller one to test   again? I had ever changed the text size to 50, then the text became normal but without smooth edge.

Comment: @Loong Again No issue on windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: @olive hmm, sounds it's a bug of qt4 on Ubuntu...

Comment: Do you have another font that you can try it with?

Comment: @Merlin069 I try several fonts, and it becomes normal when only drawText() once. I edited my question above.

Comment: I notice your timer is connected to repaint(), you're better off connecting to update() so that Qt can optimize the painting and reduce flicker. With repaint, your code might be in the middle of the paint function when the timer triggers to paint again. That could cause problems with the fact that you're changing the text pointer in the function too.

Comment: @Merlin069 I then connect the timeout singal to a new method called onChanged(), within I call update(). The situation is not changing. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: @Merlin069 Also, I set the interval of timer much longer which is 1000ms.

Comment: @Merlin069 The wierd thing is when I firstly draw the text into an image, then draw that image. It's all ok.

Comment: As @olive states that it works on Windows, then it does sound like a bug with Ubuntu. There's a possibility that Qt 5 may have a fix for it, so you could give that a try, else report it as a bug.

Comment: @Merlin069 qt 5.1.1 is still not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes below can solve the upside down problem:

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    qglClearColor(QColor(0,0,0));
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.beginNativePainting();
    renderText(-offset, 60, 0, text, QFont("YaHei Consolas Hybrid", 40, 1, false));
    painter.endNativePainting();
}
```

Comment: What is this `-offset` value?